# How to run some commands not specific to windows in DOS from Java

Tags: java, java-native-interface, runtime

I have a C++ based command line tool which has some commands to run and expect output from the same.
The process will be :
**First I need to go to the tool folder like -**

> c:>cd C:\CHECKSOFT

**Then I need to run a command like**

> C:\CHECKSOFT>bin\checktrans -f x2.in > x2.out

The above code will generate a file x2.out, then I need to read the output.

So how to execute all above processes in java.

I tried to create directory and all those basic DOS commands and those worked but I couldn't manage to make the above process to work .

What I tried-

```
public class ExecuteDOSCommand {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final String dosCommand = "cmd /c bin/checktrans -f x2.in > x2.out";
      final String location = "C:\\CHECKSOFT";
      try {
         final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            dosCommand + " " + location);
         final InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
         System.out.println("IIII "+in.read());
         int ch;
         while((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char)ch);
         }
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You would create a ProcessBuilder object to create a Process. Surely you've looked this up, right? What have you tried along these lines?

Comment: added what I tried , not processBuilder. I will check with processBuilder .

Comment: Yes ProcessBuilder worked very well. :-)

Comment: Cool! Glad you've got things working!